# C# Execute Perl Script - Syntax issue?

Tags: c#, perl

As the title says, having issues executing a particular Perl script from a C# program. I have done it successfully in the past and even within the same program. However, this particular script is resulting in a load of "Invalid Operation Exception: No process is associated with this object."

The troubled code snippet is below. The exceptions are thrown at         "perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;"

```
 public void ParseReviews(string asin)
    {
        string args = @"'C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Amazon-downloader-master\\extractAmazonReviews-DivLayout.pl '" + "'C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Amazon-downloader-master\\amazonreviews\\com\\'" + asin + "'\\ > C:\\reviews.csv'"; 
        ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe");
        perlStartInfo.Arguments = args;
        perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


        Process perl = new Process();
        perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
           perl.Start();
    }
```

The perl script can be found here below. I can execute the "downloadAmazonReviews" without a hitch using the same code. The extractAmazonReviews gives me the issue. 
https://github.com/aesuli/Amazon-downloader

It executes fine with the same arguments from CMD terminal. I am thinking i am doing something wrong with spaces and string literals but i cannot figure it out. I've tried without the ' for literals and different combinations.

Here is the test ASIN number if you want to give it  try: B00RRDTM1Q

Comment: Is there a typo in the arguments? `...-DivLayout.pl '" + "' ...` should the space be after the '

Comment: The space just needs to be removed in the file name. change `...DivLayout.pl '"` to `...DivLayout.pl'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. Silly me. I figured it out.

Apparently, the `"Filepath" > "File"` is not a valid argument. I had to remove the `> "file"`

Then change:

```
perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
```

to

```
 perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True;
```

and then read the output using that std out.

```
perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Thanks for the suggestions guys.